# Python library for a JSON server on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, architecture, webserver, client-server

I am planning to use an RPi as a server that only talks in and listens to JSON objects.

The idea is for remote management of the RPi from one windows PC available on the local LAN.

Which python library is best for such simple use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about running a [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)ful service in your RPi.

If you wanted it to be simple and bootstrap a quick application use [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) framework or [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

Instead, if you want to have a REST application with loads of features ready to use with most of the standards satisfied already for you, use [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) with [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

Comment: I can use a RESTful server, but my application needs do not strictly conform to a CRUD type process. Ex. One command to the Pi is an apt-get update.

Comment: I believe, you can still implement that using a web service. Here is an example from Digital Ocean API's https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/v2/#shutdown-a-droplet

Comment: Is there any library that only receives and outputs json documents over http, leaving the processing of the documents to the application? Can the frameworks you have mentioned above be configured to work as such?

Comment: Definitely, you can with the above mentioned frameworks. On a quick search I found this http://mattrichardson.com/Raspberry-Pi-Flask/ . Hope you'll get inspiration from this or look for other similar apps.